# Swift: Cant access let outside a method

Tags: ios, swift

I have a question.

I have the following method:

```
   func CheckJSON(json: JSON) {
        for data in json["index"].arrayValue {

            let title = data["name"].stringValue
            let body = data["profil"].stringValue
            let obj = ["title": title, "body": body]
            objects.append(obj)
}


        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I would like to access the constant 'body' outside of my function and also outside of this file.

I already tried it like this:

```
   func CheckJSON(json: JSON) -> String {
    for data in json["index"].arrayValue {

        let title = data["name"].stringValue
        let body = data["profil"].stringValue
        let obj = ["title": title, "body": body]
        objects.append(obj)



    }

    tableView.reloadData()
    return body
}
```

But i get the Error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'body'

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the variable is limited to the for loop itself.
When you declare a variable inside a loop you cant access it outside the loop.The scope of the variable is limited within the loop. If you want this you should declare the variable outside the loop, so you could use it in your function as a return.

So the code would look like this:

```
// Right now you can acces the variable within the same file, and within a different file anywhere you want.    
var body: String! // Or a different type you want to give the variable
func CheckJSON(json: JSON) -> String {
  for data in json["index"].arrayValue {
    let title = data["name"].stringValue
    body = data["profil"].stringValue
    let obj = ["title": title, "body": body]
    objects.append(obj)
  }

  tableView.reloadData()
  return body
}
```

You can acces the variable outside a file with the following code:

```
// change instance to the name of your own class
var instance = exampleViewController()
// Call the variable.
instance.body
```

Comment: Thanks but i get a Error in the following line: objects.append(obj)

Comment: The Error:  Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '([String : String!])'

Comment: Change it to var body = ""

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now i can access body outside of my function. But how do i access it outside of my file? I have a masterviewcontroller and a detailviewcontroller. the declaration of body is inside the masterviewcontroller. How do i access "body" inside of the detailviewcontroller?

Comment: Make an instance of the class that the body variable is in and then call the variable on the instance. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: I changed var body = "" to: var body = MasterViewController() but now i get the error:  Cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'MasterViewController'

Comment: That's not the way you need to do it, you should keep the body variable as var body = "". But in the file you want to acces body you have to create an instance like i explained in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! But now i get the following error:  Expression resolves to an unused l-value. Sorry if i ask a lot, im a "Swift beginner"

Comment: I can't help you with all the stuff because I don't have all of your code. Also these thing are some basic knowledge that you should acquire before you ask a question here.

Comment: I solved it :D I misspelled something wrong!! Thanks btw :D

Comment: Okay:-). But i would suggest to take a look at some basic swift stuff. So you know how Swift works. Apple has a great site explaining everything about Swift;)